# IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I am trying to use `CursorAdapter` with `ListView`, but logcat shows this message:

> "IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist"

This belongs from main activity:

```
ContactDatabase onbOfContactDatabase=new ContactDatabase(getBaseContext());

Cursor mCursor= onbOfContactDatabase.phoneName();

String[] fromFileName=new String[]{ContactDatabase.NAME,ContactDatabase.PHONE};
int[] toViewId=new int[]{R.id.textView5,R.id.textView6};
SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;

simpleCursorAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.forreading,mCursor,fromFileName,toViewId,0);
 ListView myListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
 myListView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
```

This belongs from database:

```
public class ContactDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="totalContact.db";
    public static final  String TABLE_NAME="mecontact";
    public static final  String NAME="name";
    public static final  String PHONE="phone";


    public ContactDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("create table mecontact" +
                    "(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, phone text)");
        }catch(android.database.SQLException e){
                System.out.println("table create nhi ho rha");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mecontact");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertContact(String nam,String mob){

        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(NAME,nam);
        contentValues.put(PHONE,mob);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }
    public Cursor phoneName(){

        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mecontact ", null);
        return res;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `id` to `_id`. `SimpleCursorAdapter` needs a column with this name.

```
db.execSQL("create table mecontact" +
                "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, phone text)");
```

If you don't want to rename your column name the you will have to use alias in your select query.